# Create associative array from string

Tags: php, string, associative-array

How can I convert this string "1,2,3,4," to this assoc array

```
array('id' => '1', 'id' => '2', 'id' => '3', 'id' => '4');
```

With explode() I get this `array('1','2','3','4')`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by setting each index to 'id'?

Comment: I want to pass them as arguments to a function that expects the 'id'

Comment: What's the function definition? Does it expect an array with the "id" key or has it a parameter named id? In the latter case, only the position of the value matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, the index of array must be unique.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Then I should wrap each 'id' => '1' in an array by itself and have a mutlidimension array?

Comment: However, array(array('id'=>'1'), array('id'=>'2'), ...) is possible.

Comment: @chchrist: Just keep the numbers in a simple array and wrap them on the spot when you need to pass them as parameters.